# Getting rejected by urlscan after login on a subdomain

Tags: asp.net, authentication, subdomain, urlscan

I'm seeing a strange problem on a asp.net 2.0 web site. If I login to a subdomain and then come to the main domain, clicking any links on the Home page causes rejected-by-url-scan errors with the link urls shown in the web log as beginning with tilde. What can be this problem?

Comment: You need to find out where in your code the tilde is created and correct the code to render an absolute URL.

Comment: But there is no tilde in the main domain links. The problem occurs only after login to a subdomain. So the login somehow starts adding a tilde. I will now inspect my subdomain code. Meanwhile, can you give a more specific clue?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a UrlScan problem that after a recent update of the host, started rejecting any queries with special characters in them. It occurred only when cookies were present because the value in some cookies had special characters.

Once I found the reason, I was looking to switch on the special flag in UrlScan that allows special characters. But I could not do it successfully in web.config. It has to be done at IIS level for each web site. I'm debating whether to do it for security reasons. The idea of the new UrlScan feature is good for stopping attacks.

Meanwhile, I added some initialization code to delete the old cookies and recreate them with encrypted values so that special characters are not encountered. But even the initialization code could not run in some cases so I also had to add it in the final error processing page for automatic recovery.

Comment: I discovered that as soon as I create any cookie on the subdomain, its own path resolution for root relative paths is broken on next loading. It works only when I delete the cookie. Since this problem has started recently, seems to be a web host problem now. Any ideas if some IIS setting or web.config can cause this problem?